# pop method in implemented LinkedQueue is removing all values and not the first one

Tags: java, intellij-idea, linked-list, queue

With this implementation of a LinkedQueue, all the methods except the pop() method work fine. When using the pop() method all of the values in the stack disappear making it empty when it is supposed to remove the first value only

Here is the LinkedQueue class

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

    public class LinkedQueue
    {
        Node front, rear;
        int size;

        public LinkedQueue()
        {
            front = null;
            rear = null;
            size = 0;
        }

        public boolean isEmpty()
        {
            if(front == null)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        public int getSize()
        {
            return size;
        }

        public void push(int data)
        {
            Node n = new Node(data);
            if(isEmpty())
                front = rear = n;
            else
            {
                rear.setLink(n);
                rear = n;
            }

            size++;
        }

        public int pop()
        {
            Node temp = new Node(front.getData());
            if(isEmpty())
            {
                throw new IllegalAccessError();
            }
            else
            {
                front = temp.getLink();
                size--;
            }

            return temp.getData();
        }

        public int peek()
        {
            if (isEmpty())
            {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("Stack is empty.");
            }
            else
            {
                return front.getData();
            }
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            Node tempFront = front;
            String returnStr = "Stack: [";
            while(tempFront != null)
            {
                returnStr += tempFront.getData() + ", ";
                tempFront = tempFront.getLink();
            }

            returnStr += "]";

            return returnStr;
        }
    }
```

Here is the Driver used for the LinkedQueue class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Driver
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            //declare variables and initialize scanner
            Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
            int size, choice, value, end;

            end = 0;

            //declare and initialize the stack
            LinkedQueue queue1 = new LinkedQueue();

            //loop to continue operations
            while(end == 0)
            {
                //print out menu for commands
                System.out.println("\t1) Push \n\t2) Pop \n\t3) Peek \n\t4) Size \n\t5) isEmpty \n\t6) End");
                System.out.print("Please choose an option: ");
                choice = key.nextInt();

                //switch the choice and execute commands
                switch (choice)
                {
                    case 1: System.out.println("Please enter a value: ");
                        value = key.nextInt();
                        queue1.push(value);
                        System.out.println(queue1.toString());
                        break;
                    case 2: queue1.pop();
                        System.out.println(queue1.toString());
                        break;
                    case 3: queue1.peek();
                        System.out.println(queue1.peek());
                        System.out.println(queue1.toString());
                        break;
                    case 4: System.out.println("Size: " + queue1.getSize());
                        System.out.println(queue1.toString());
                        break;
                    case 5: if(queue1.isEmpty())
                    {
                        System.out.println("Stack is empty.");
                    }
                    else
                        System.out.println("Stack is NOT empty.");
                        System.out.println(queue1.toString());
                        break;
                    case 6: end = 1;
                        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have also made my own Node class

```
public class Node
{
    int data;
    Node link;

    //contructor
    public Node(int d)
    {
        data =  d;
        link = null;
    }

    public int getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public Node getLink()
    {
        return link;
    }

    public void setData(int d)
    {
        data = d;
    }

    public void setLink(Node n)
    {
        link = n;
    }
}
```

As mentioned before the only issue I have is with the pop() method, but if you see any other errors that will also help, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
front = temp.getLink();
```

with

```
front = front.getLink();
```